# How to determine object type

Tags: r, type-conversion, terminology

Here is how my object displays:

```
> object
 [1] "string1"
 [2] "string2"                 
 [3] "string3"
```

What is that object type called? How do I change it to a vector like this (without manually typing the whole thing out):

```
> c("string1","string2","string3")
[1] "string1"    "string2"    "string3"
```

All the methods I tried just gave me back the same object.

```
> as.vector(object)
> unlist(object)
```

Edit: Thanks for your help. I think it was a vector to begin with.

Comment: `dput(object)` possibly? Maybe worth trying `str(object)` to see what sort of object it is.

Comment: `typeof`, `class` and `str` should be helpful. If the object results from `method(...)`, `?method` gives more information about the object generated (check the *value* subsection). As a last resort, you could remove the unwanted class with brute force viz. `unclass`.

Comment: Best guess? Your vector has a class attribute and your environment has a matching `print` method to print it just like that. Like the others suggest: `str`, ' class', etc. might shed some light on this. The [huh!? package](https://github.com/SigurdJanson/huh) should help, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to be a list of 3 elements which would typically appear like this in the console:

```
[[1]]
[1] "string1"

[[2]]
[1] "string2"

[[3]]
[1] "string3"
```

If you can, do `str(object)` or `class(object)` as recommended above to find out more. Once you see if there is an internal structure you may be able to do something like `object$substructure` to get at this. Could you let us know what `str()` gives you? It will help answer.